# Trying to lower the number of apache 2 process

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, lamp

I am on Debian 6 LAMP with apache mpm_prefork

I have

```
Timeout 20
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 80
KeepAliveTimeout 2

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    ServerLimit      500
    MaxClients            500
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1500
</IfModule>
```

with 4GB of RAM. The problem is Apache2 starts too many process. Whenever I do `top` I see most of time only 1 running, while the number of apache2 process sleeping grows over time (now at 437 processes and counting)

Can I know Why apache2 starts new process instead to use the one already opened? And how can i tell to apache to don't open so many process?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've told Apache that you want to be able to service 500 clients simultaneously and have a hard limit on the client process pool of 500.

As Apache receives requests it will start to expand its process pool until it gets to near your limit.

Because you're using a preforking server, each process only handles a single request thread, so Apache needs to maintain a large number of sleeping processes in order to handle up to the number of simultaneous clients you've specified. These eat a lot of memory.

You can either switch to a threading MPM model, reduce the value of MaxClients or increase the amount of RAM. See both http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html.

Comment: thanks for the reply +1. But I heard with PHP i can only use prefork (it was installed automatically with apt-get) anyway I will try to lower maxclients and serverlimit to 400

Comment: PHP recommend to use a preforked MPM model. Aside from non-threadsafe PHP modules and a general sense of "We like separate processes because threads are difficult", I'm not sure really why this is. Depending on how popular your site is, I'd set the apache settings to be fairly conservative and then monitor closely to see how performance is affected by load.

Comment: @growse: AWW maybe i found my problem. While moving my website to the new server i forgot to load mod_expires so everytime users moved in my website had to request for each image/css/js a new request. That caused so many more connections to handle by apache2. I now activated mod_expires i will monitor the situtation

Comment: Ah, that wouldn't help :) People often forget that loading a modern web page can result in tens of connections being created. On a prefork model, this will bump the process count significantly.

Comment: I am pretty sure that was the cause... I wonder why apache2 doesn't come with expires in the default installation. This webserver really lacks